# Change/Add Image Title and Alt within a WordPress Post

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to replace alt and title properties of all the images present in a WordPress post/page using jQuery with the post title.

I tried several codes, but nothing is working can you please help me on this?

Here is one of code I tried. Looks like it should work, but it isn't.

```
<?php function ia_prop_js() { 
global $post; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".hentry" ).find("img").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("title", "<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title($post->ID)); ?>");
            $(this).attr("alt", "<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title($post->ID)); ?>");
    });
});
</script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_head', 'ia_prop_js');
?>
```

Comment: what is the problem? have you tries modifying the title/alt with static text and what what happens? have you tried selecting images using `$(".hentry img")`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I even tried jQuery no-conflict mode codes.

Comment: i made a simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd84e/) which appears to work fine. either provide a url or modify this fiddle to better help you

Comment: Strangely my code works on every other WordPress blogs except one. Here is the URL http://www.bg-eu.com/product/test-product-001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your test url if I this on the console

```
jQuery( ".hentry" ).find("img").each(function() {
       jQuery(this).attr("title", "new");
       jQuery(this).attr("alt", "new");
});
```

it changes title and alt. So either it is the `$` or your `get_the_title` does not return a title (maybe is outside the loop)

Comment: That's exactly it. As soon as I hooked this in wp_footer, this piece is working. :) Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img.hentry').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("title", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
            $(this).attr("alt", "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    });
});
```

please also have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/4qgaX/

Comment: You got it all wrong mate. The image is inside of a div with hentry class.

Answer (score 0):

Use these two functions,these will help a lot: This both are tested

```
/**
 * Rename the Media/image filename to Post title
 * Example: title I love icecream - filename: i-love-icecream-23.jpg
 *
 */

function wpsx_5505_modify_uploaded_file_names($arr) {

    // Get the parent post ID, if there is one
    if( isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ) {
        $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
    } else {
        $post_id = false;
    }

    // Only do this if we got the post ID--otherwise they're probably in
    //  the media section rather than uploading an image from a post.
    if($post_id && is_numeric($post_id)) {

          // Get the post title
        $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);

          // Get the post slug
        $post_slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $post_title);

        // If we found a slug
        if($post_slug) {

            $random_number = rand(10000,99999);
            $arr['name'] = $post_slug . '-' . $random_number . '.jpg';

        }

    }

    return $arr;

}
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wpsx_5505_modify_uploaded_file_names', 1, 1);
```

To add filename to caption and Title,use code below

```
/**
 * Add the Media/Image filename to caption, Title
 *
 */
function wpsx_5505_modify_uploaded_file_meta($meta, $file, $sourceImageType) {

    // Get the parent post ID, if there is one
    if( isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ) {
        $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
    } else {
        $post_id = false;
    }

    // Only do this if we got the post ID--otherwise they're probably in
    //  the media section rather than uploading an image from a post.
    if($post_id && is_numeric($post_id)) {

        // Get the post title
        $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);

        // If we found a title
        if($post_title) {

            $meta['title'] = $post_title;
            $meta['caption'] = $post_title;


        }

    }

    return $meta;

}
add_filter('wp_read_image_metadata', 'wpsx_5505_modify_uploaded_file_meta', 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this plugin**

The Alt Manager plugin is a simple plugin that changes images Alt and Title attributes text on your (Pages – Posts) separately to your website name or (post or page) title.This Plugin bulk changes images Alt and Title attribues immediately you dont need to change image info on media library.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/alt-manager/